# flex bison : creating multiple character variable

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I want to create a programming language consisting multiple character variables (e.g. abc=10, num=120). I was able to create single character variable . The .y code is :

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
                  //char sym[1000];
    //int x=0;
    int sym[26];

%}


%token NUMBER ADD SUB MUL DIV ABS EOL ID ASS
%%
calclist : 
    | calclist exp EOL   { printf("= %d\n", $2); } 
    | ID ASS exp EOL     { sym[$1] = $3;

             }
;
exp:    factor           { $$=$1; }
    | exp ADD factor     { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | exp SUB factor     { $$ = $1 - $3; }
;
factor :    term         { $$=$1; }
    | factor MUL term    { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | factor DIV term    { $$ = $1 / $3; }
;
term :  NUMBER       { $$=$1; }

;

%%
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
yyparse();
}
yyerror(char *s)
{
fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}
```

and the .l code is :

```
%{
# include "P3.tab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern int yylval;
//int m=0;
%}

%%
"+"     { return ADD; }
"-"     { return SUB; }
"*"  { return MUL; }
"/"     { return DIV; }
"=" { return ASS; }
[a-z]+  { yylval= *yytext  - 'a' ;  
     return ID ; }
[0-9]+  { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n   { return EOL; }
[ \t]   { /* ignore whitespace */ }
.    { printf("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%
int yywrap()
{
return 1;
}
```

So, with this code , I can only create a=10,x=90 kind of single character variable . How can I create multiple character variable And I also want to check if it is already declared or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has very little to do with bison or flex. In fact, your flex patterns already recognise multi-character identifiers (as long as they are purely alphabetic), but the action ignores characters after the first.

What you need is some kind of associative container like a hash table, which you could use as a symbol table instead of the vector `sym`.

The Bison manual includes a number of small example calculator programs. See, for example,  [mfcalc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Multi_002dfunction-Calc), which includesa symbol table implemented as a simple linear association list.

Comment: how will I check if my variable is declared or not ? Do I need to traverse through the linked list? It was not that much of helpful:(

Comment: @jane: the sample code does essentially what you want to do. It works and it's coding style is pretty clear (IMHO). And it has helped many people over the years. Anyway, the answer is yes and the sample code does that (in the lexer iirc).